# Accuracy of the model is not improving despite trying different optimizers and batch sizes

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

im having 12 classes with 4456 images

```
    IMAGE_SIZE = (255, 255)
    trainpath = "/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/trainset"
    testpath = "/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/testset"
```

im using vgg16

```
    vgg = VGG16(("input_shape = IMAGE_SIZE + [3], weights='imagenet', include_top=False"))
    for layer in vgg.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
    folders = glob('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/trainset')
```

And also im having some erroe when flatting the error is ValueError: The name "flatten" is used 2 times in the model. All layer names should be unique. im doing it in colab

```
    x =Flatten()(vgg.output)
    prediction = Dense(units=12, activation="sigmoid")(x)
    
    model = Model(inputs=vgg.input, outputs=prediction)
    model.summary()
    Model: "model_1"
    _________________________________________________________________
    Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
    =================================================================
    input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 224, 224, 3)]     0         
    _________________________________________________________________
    block1_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 224, 224, 64)      1792      
    _________________________________________________________________
    block1_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 224, 224, 64)      36928     
    _________________________________________________________________
    block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 112, 112, 64)      0         
    _________________________________________________________________
    block2_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 112, 112, 128)     73856     
    _________________________________________________________________
    block2_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 112, 112, 128)     147584    
    _________________________________________________________________
    block2_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 56, 56, 128)       0         
    _________________________________________________________________
    block3_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       295168    
    _________________________________________________________________
    block3_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       590080    
    _________________________________________________________________
    block3_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       590080    
    _________________________________________________________________
    block3_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 28, 28, 256)       0         
    _________________________________________________________________
    block4_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 28, 28, 512)       1180160   
    _________________________________________________________________
    block4_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 28, 28, 512)       2359808   
    _________________________________________________________________
    block4_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 28, 28, 512)       2359808   
    _________________________________________________________________
    block4_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 14, 14, 512)       0         
    _________________________________________________________________
    block5_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
    _________________________________________________________________
    block5_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
    _________________________________________________________________
    block5_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
    _________________________________________________________________
    block5_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 7, 7, 512)         0         
    _________________________________________________________________
    flatten (Flatten)            (None, 25088)             0         
    _________________________________________________________________
    fc1 (Dense)                  (None, 4096)              102764544 
    _________________________________________________________________
    fc2 (Dense)                  (None, 4096)              16781312  
    _________________________________________________________________
    predictions (Dense)          (None, 1000)              4097000   
    _________________________________________________________________
    flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 1000)              0         
    _________________________________________________________________
    dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 12)                12012     
    =================================================================
    Total params: 138,369,556
    Trainable params: 12,012
    Non-trainable params: 138,357,544
    
    model.compile(
                  loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  optimizer='adam',
                  metrics=['accuracy']
                  )
    
    from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
    
    train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.5/255,
                                       shear_range = 0.2,
                                       zoom_range = 0.2,
                                       horizontal_flip = True)
    test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.5/255)
    
    training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/trainset',
                                                      target_size = (244,244),
                                                      batch_size = 62,
                                                     class_mode = 'categorical')
    test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/testset',
                                                 target_size =(244,244),
                                                 batch_size = 62,
                                                class_mode = 'categorical')
    
    r = model.fit_generator(
        training_set,
        validation_data = test_set,enter code here
        epochs = 10,
        steps_per_epoch = len(training_set),
        validation_steps = len(test_set)
    )
```

Here the accuracy is gettin stuck first i tried with 32 batches and the accuray is around 51 and it stucks there and now im trying with 62 batches now im getting the accuray with 45

```
Epoch 1/10
    26/72 [=========>....................] - ETA: 28:21 - loss: 2.4641 - accuracy: 0.4340/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py:770: UserWarning: Possibly corrupt EXIF data.  Expecting to read 8 bytes but only got 2. Skipping tag 41486
      " Skipping tag %s" % (size, len(data), tag)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py:770: UserWarning: Possibly corrupt EXIF data.  Expecting to read 8 bytes but only got 0. Skipping tag 41487
      " Skipping tag %s" % (size, len(data), tag)
    72/72 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.4351 - accuracy: 0.4503
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I think your target size in your data generator should be `(224,224)` instead of `(244,244)`.

And since you are using a pre-trained model, the problem most likely is coming from your dataset.
To know more about your problem you should see how well your model is predicting. Use this to draw a heatmap for your data predictions:

```
Y_pred = model.predict(test_set)
y_pred = np.argmax(Y_pred, axis=1)
plt.figure(figsize=(30,30))
sns.heatmap(confusion_matrix(test_set.classes, y_pred), cmap="YlGnBu", annot=True, fmt="d")
```

After that, you can see which class the model is doing right. There may be some common problem:

- Unbalanced dataset: you have too many data on one class and too few on others
- The model always predict one class:

My suggestion is to just run the model to see how it works.

Comment: You can use upsampling which means collect more data for the classes that are too few or downsampling which means remove data from the class that has too many

Comment: well you should share permission but better yet post the result on your questions

Comment: sir i have plotted the prediction at 2241 im having high error i had shared the permission https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1tbp0C47d8dOaRnkOYoxZhJuQjVBs0KB2?usp=sharing check this please dont mine sir that im sharing a link please help me with my project i will very thank full to you please